# How to get the progress of a timer made with SetTimer()

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there any way to get the current progress of a timer, which is created by the SetTimer function?

Comment: What do you mean by 'current progress'? Do you wish to find out (a) how long since it was initially created or (b) how long since it fired last or (c) how long till it will fire next?

Comment: No.  Store the return value of GetTickCount() in a variable when you start the timer.  Update it in the WM_TIMER handler.  Now you always know how much time is left, simply by subtracting that variable value from GetTickCount().

Comment: The solution with GetTickCount() seems reasonable, I'll add an answer as soon as i implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation of Hans' comment. Clicking the button shows the time remaining until the next scheduled (expected) WM_TIMER message. By building in debug mode, I get a console to display my messages, since it's such a quick and easy (read: dirty) way of getting both a GUI and a console.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "resource.h"

HINSTANCE hInst;

DWORD tickCountInitial;
DWORD timerInterval = 10000;
DWORD nextTimerFired;

BOOL CALLBACK DlgMain(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            tickCountInitial = GetTickCount();
            SetTimer(hwndDlg, 666, timerInterval, NULL);
            nextTimerFired = tickCountInitial + timerInterval;
        }
        return TRUE;

        case WM_TIMER:
        {
            DWORD tickCountCurrent = GetTickCount();
            printf("Ticks elapsed: %d\n", tickCountCurrent - tickCountInitial);
            nextTimerFired = tickCountCurrent + timerInterval;
            MessageBeep(MB_OK);
        }
        return 0;

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
        }
        return TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDC_BUTTON1:
                {
                    DWORD tickCountCurrent = GetTickCount();
                    printf("Ticks till next WM_TIMER message: %d\n", nextTimerFired - tickCountCurrent);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    hInst=hInstance;
    InitCommonControls();
    return DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DlgMain);
}
```

**resource.h**

```
#ifndef IDC_STATIC
#define IDC_STATIC (-1)
#endif

#define DLG_MAIN                                100
#define IDC_BUTTON1                             40000
```

**resource.rc**

```
// Generated by ResEdit 1.6.2
// Copyright (C) 2006-2014
// http://www.resedit.net

#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <richedit.h>
#include "resource.h"




//
// Dialog resources
//
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
DLG_MAIN DIALOG 0, 0, 186, 95
STYLE DS_3DLOOK | DS_CENTER | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SHELLFONT | WS_CAPTION | WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "Ms Shell Dlg"
{
    PUSHBUTTON      "Check Remaining", IDC_BUTTON1, 41, 32, 104, 31, 0, WS_EX_LEFT
}



//
// Manifest resources
//
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
1                  RT_MANIFEST    ".\\manifest.xml"
```